# How to find out if a user exists in a db using sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use `sp_executesql` but can't seem to get the syntax right to do so. Here is what I'm trying out:

```
DECLARE @userName1 varchar(20)
DECLARE @userexists bit

SET @userName1 = 'testUser'

EXEC sp_executesql N'select @userexists = name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = ' + @userName1, N'@userexists bit output', @userexists output

PRINT @userexists
```

How can this work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to use it in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
  N'select @userexists=1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @userName1',
  N'@userName1 varchar(20), @userexists bit output',
  @userName1,
  @userexists output
```

In this case you will get `1` or empty result.

So, you can try this :

```
 EXEC sp_executesql 
  N'SET @userexists = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                FROM  sys.database_principals
                                WHERE name = @userName1)
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0
                       END',
  N'@userName1 varchar(20), @userexists bit output',
  @userName1,
  @userexists output
```

Comment: works great thx, using the second solution to fit my problem i try adding 'use DB\@name;' before the SET \@userexists' but it doesn't resolve the \@name part. \@name is a varchar(50) and is used to loop through lots of dbs.   it returns 'DB\@name' doesn't exist.  any idea what i can try ... tx you again.

Comment: i posted the followup question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175850/how-to-loop-dbs-using-sp-executesql

Comment: @user1161137 Hello. Glad to have been of help. I'm sorry, I've just read the comment :( and it seems too late