# how to loop dbs using sp_executesql

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Follow up question to   [sp execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173407/how-to-find-out-if-a-user-exists-in-a-db-using-sp-executesql/41173700#41173700)

I'd like to loop through a list of dbs names that are stored in a cursor, and i don't know what works in integrating a USE command to the sp execute command, since i need that statement to work against changing dbs.

i've tried the code below but sp_executesql returns a syntax error on @dbfullname. (after understanding more the definition of sp_executesql, i'm thinking there is no way to add that USE command. So how else can this be done? any pointers? does it need to be done in a batch transaction?)

```
        declare @dbfullname varchar(60)
        declare @name varchar(50)
        DECLARE @userName1 varchar(20)
        DECLARE @userexists bit

        SET @userName1 = 'testUser'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @dbfullname = N'MyDb' + @name

        EXEC sp_executesql  N'use @dbfullname; SET @userexists = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                FROM  sys.database_principals
                                WHERE name = @userName1)
                                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                                   END',
                            N'@userName1 varchar(20), @userExists bit output',
                            @userName1,
                            @userExists output

    END
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`USE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) does not accept a variable or expression, only a static database name.

You can assemble the command prior to the `EXEC`, e.g.:

```
set @dbfullname = N'MyDb' + @name;
declare @SQL as NVarChar(1000) = N'use ' + @dbfullname +
  N'; set @userExists = case when exists ...;';
exec SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @userName1, @userExists output;
```

Note that if there is any possibility of a naughty value in `@dbfullname` that this exposes you to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: it's to do a batch update of sorts, so in full control of data

Comment: trying to do what you said but not letting me define a nvarchar for some reason. so getting the error procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Comment: ah ok.. i initialized the nvarchar too high... i had done nvarchar(6000) and it wouldn't work.. didn't check the upper limit.  once i  did that... that solved the issue following breaking down the statement.

Comment: @user1161137 Sorry, I was a bit too slow adding to the sample code. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

as per Habo.. his solution resolved my problem .. i just wanted to post what i changed for those who might not follow exactly what changed. Note must use nvarchar because of sp_executesql requires it.

```
        declare @nsql nvarchar(1000)

        SET @nsql = N'use ' + @dbfullname + N'; SET @userexists = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 ' +
                                ' FROM  sys.database_principals ' +
                                ' WHERE name = @userName1) ' +
                                ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 ' +
                                '   END'

        EXEC sp_executesql @nsql, 
                            N'@userName1 varchar(20), @userExists bit output',
                            @userName1,
                            @userExists output
```